# R: how to find the index of the second/third/...n-1th smallest value in a list

Tags: r, list

```
mylist <- list(1.3, 2, -3, 0, 20)
> mylist
[[1]]
[1] 1.3

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] -3

[[4]]
[1] 0

[[5]]
[1] 20
```

I want to find the index of the second smallest entry in the list. In this case, it should be `4`. I know that `which.min(mylist)` gives me the index of the smallest entry. However, what's the quickest way to find the index of the `m < n`th smallest entry, given a list of length `n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `order` on the `unlist`ed `list` and extract the 2nd element

```
order(unlist(mylist))[2]
#[1] 4
```

---

A function can be created with it

```
f1 <- function(lstA, n){
        order(unlist(lstA))[n]
  }
f1(mylist, 2)
#[1] 4
f1(mylist, 3)
#[1] 1
```